# Does Phriction (the wiki in Phabricator) offer a Templates feature like MediaWiki?

Tags: templates, wiki, phabricator

Does [Phriction](https://www.phacility.com/phabricator/phriction/) (the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki) offered as part of [Phabricator](https://www.phacility.com/phabricator/)) offer a  markup feature like the [Templates](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates) in [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/)?

---

In the past I have used [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/) (the software that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/) is run on) as an internal wiki at a company.  This means that I am relatively fluent in its markup, features and terminology.

Within MediaWiki there is a powerful feature, Templates, that allows you to insert boiler plate markup using a pseudonym such as `{{foo}}`.  This is a user definable entry that causes instances of `{{foo}}` on a page to be replaced by markup test such as `A simple example bit of _data_ to fill a space`.

More complex templates could be created by nesting one template inside another.  A call to `{{foo}}` might include a call to `{{bar}}` within it and so on.  This allowed you to form complex bits of text from simple lumps.

The really interesting feature of templates was in using [parameters](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates#Parameters) with them.  Ideally this is what I would like to use within Phriction, if possible.  A template with a parameter is called by something like `{{foo|var1}}`.  Now inside the text you can insert the 'var1' into the generated text to give you something such as `var1 is a simple example bit of _data_ to fill a space`.

What you really use this for is something like an RFC link template.  You can add `{{rfc|123}}` to a page then have the template generate some markup like `[[ https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc123.txt | RFC123 ]]`.  What is the advantage of this?  Well perhaps you decide next week that you want all your RFC's to reference the copies on https://www.rfc-editor.org/ instead.  Or you decide that you want links to both the .txt on ietf.org and rfc-editor.org.  By using the template you can create a single article to edit in the future to make a consistent view across your wiki.

Any suggestions that can provide a step towards the above goal would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Phriction is just Remarkup. https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/remarkup/